# Asp.NET not getting updated values of custom attributes set by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, vb.net

This problem has been bugging me and any explanation of why this is would help.

Given the following DOM:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="myDiv" runat="server" data-type="Monkey">
        Choose your inner animal!
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">Monkey</li>
            <li>Tiger</li>
            <li>Dog</li>
            <li>Bunny</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />

</form>
</body>
<script src="Assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li').bind('click', function () {
        $('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        var animal = $(this).addClass('selected').text();

        //$('#myDiv').data('type', animal);
        $('#myDiv').attr('data-type', animal);
    });

});
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim type As String = myDiv.Attributes("data-type")

    MsgBox(type)
End Sub
End Class
```

The MsgBox **always** comes back with the default value of 'Monkey'.  Now i did implement a workaround where I stored the value in a Hidden field, then recalled the value on button click and that works. I did try an update panel but no luck, but that doesn't really matter because I hate update panels and never use them anyways.

Comment: update panels are amazing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limit - if you want to call it that - of HTML and the way things post back.  It's not even an ASP.NET limit, as far as I am aware: it goes beyond that.

Only certain tags have their values posted back to the server.  I'm thinking it's just INPUT and SELECT tags, although there may be one I'm not thinking of.

Attributes in tags don't even get posted back: just values.

So the server doesn't know anything about what you've changed on the client, unless it's what's selected in a SELECT or the value of an INPUT.  Everything in ASP.NET, everything that gets reconstructed from ViewState and postback data, is based on those tags.

So your hidden field is the only way what you want can happen.

Comment: +1 Ann is correct. Attributes are not posted back at all. Only input elements (any input element, radio, checkbox, select, text ,etc..) that have a NAME attribute are posted back. Also, `disabled` input elements are NOT posted back either even if they have a NAME attribute.

Comment: Ya that makes sense, guess i didn't really think it through

Comment: @Sam  I knew I'd forgotten one!

Answer (score 0):

In case of SELECT, if the "disabled" attribute is set to true in JQuery then in ASP .Net code-behind, you will not get the correct values but instead, you will get the first item in the list as selecteditem and it's corresponding value as selectedvalue. Same is the case for INPUT as well.

I think the simplest option is to use the hidden fields, populating them in JQuery and using their values in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Another common reason is if you rebuild the dropdown list in code behind on the page_load function without checking that it's not `IsPostBack` first.  This would cause you to reset the value each time to the default/first item.